# Mobile version - positioning & pagination product page magento

Tags: css, magento, mobile, css-position, product

I would like to ask how could I change or delete some boxes in mobile version in product page of magento. For example, in mobile version always, i don't want to show related or upsell products. But i want to keep them live in main version. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Magento comes in with built in matched expression functionality. You can read about it at the following link. In short summary though you input specific user agents and if the browser user agent matches this then a specific template will be used. The link has a more detailed write up.

http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/magento-design-exceptions-explained/